# android:theme=“@style/Theme.Holo.Light"

Tags: android

I am trying to create swipeable Tabs inside a LinearLayout created in activity_main.xml. The .MainActivity that is using   as its android:theme.
I created swipeable tabs using this link : https://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

I noticed that swipeable tabs only work when the theme for the .MainActiviy is set to @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light. Is there any way i can make swipeable tabs work by setting the .MainActivity theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: really ??? it'll "only work when the theme @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" ?

Comment: i'm using it with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and with Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Your MainActivity should extend AppCompatActivity, not Activity.